logging to file with uvicorn web-server
I'm trying to write some log messages to a file called log.txt, but I'm facing an issue while trying to do this with the Uvicorn server.
If I call the logger before creating and configuring the Uvicorn server, everything works fine. However, if I call the logger (or any other function with logging) after it, then I only get messages in stdout and not in the file.
My code looks like this:
import asyncio
import logging
import sys
import logging
from uuid import uuid4

import uvicorn
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application


# Enable logging
streamhandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
filehandler = logging.FileHandler("log.log", "w")
logging.basicConfig(handlers=[streamhandler, filehandler],
                    level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s, %(levelname)s, %(message)s, %(name)s')
# set higher logging level for httpx to avoid all GET and POST requests being logged
logging.getLogger("httpx").setLevel(logging.WARNING)


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def loger():
    logger.info("Start func")

settings.configure(ROOT_URLCONF=__name__, SECRET_KEY=uuid4().hex)


async def main() -> None:
    """Finalize configuration and run the applications."""
    # loger()
    # logger.info("Start server")

    webserver = uvicorn.Server(config=uvicorn.Config(
        app=get_asgi_application(),
        port=8010,
        use_colors=False,
        host="127.0.0.1",
    ))
    loger()
    logger.info("Start server")

    await webserver.serve()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())


I thought that problem could be with asyncio so I tried using queueHandler and queueListener:
que = Queue()
qhandler = logging.handlers.QueueHandler(que)
streamhandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
filehandler = logging.FileHandler("log.log", "w")
logging.basicConfig(handlers=[streamhandler, filehandler, qhandler],
                    level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s, %(levelname)s, %(message)s, %(name)s')
# set higher logging level for httpx to avoid all GET and POST requests being logged
logging.getLogger("httpx").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
listener = logging.handlers.QueueListener(que, filehandler)
listener.start()

But it didn't help. What I'm doing wrong?
UPD:
Changing "w" to "a" in filehandler helps, but I still have no idea why.

Did changing 'w' to 'a' resolved entirely your problem ? FYI, 'w' stands for "write" and 'a' for "append". If you use 'w' every time you write to your file, it will overwrite every previous infos. Btw, if you use 'w' you should at least see the last log wrote by your program.

@Lrx Basically yes. I was expecting that using "w" instead of "a" will clear log file after program restart.
What still disturb me - why no even single record in file when using "w"

Hi @Дмитрий Мисюра , Have you been able to find out why there was not a single record or have you moved on to something else ?
